# How to enable FTP in PHP?

Tags: php, ftp

I have the following Error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function ftp_connect()

I tested on my local and its run okey ,but in my server the error appers how i can enable ftp.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ftp.installation.php

Comment: If you're using a shared server you might not have access to php.ini whuch means that adding support for ftp might be a no go. Some companies allow you to modify php.ini though the panel settings, but if you come up a bust.. a virtual server/dedicated server may be your only option here

Comment: thanks,but the problem is that php has been compiled in my server(linux) without '--enable ftp' and i have a multple versions of php the one that apache use is support ftp,can i swith which version i will use in my script ,any advise?!